# Unable to grab selenium element for one particular class name

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, css-selectors, selenium-chromedriver

So I am trying to find elements by CSS selector using the class name. One of my code works while the other does not.

Screenshot of the html code that works:[image]

The code for the above screenshot, that works:

```
driver.get(url)
print('a') # to check if code has run till here
disabled_next = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.page-link.next.disabled')
print(disabled_next)
```

Screenshot of the html code that does NOT work:[image]

The code for the above screenshot, that does not work:

```
driver.get(url)
print('a')
enabled_next = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.page-link.next')
print(enabled_next)
```

Just trying to understand why the second one does not work. It does not even print ('a'). The error I am getting is along the lines of this:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot determine loading status
from unknown error: unexpected command response
  (Session info: chrome=103.0.5060.66)
```

I am using chromedriver103 with chrome version 103. I know there have been some issues relating to it. Could that be why? Or have I used the wrong format for '.page-link.next'.

Also, a semi-related question: How do I grab the text after <a class = "text here"? I would like to just grab "text here". So in my examples above I would love to grab "page-link next disabled" or "page-link next".

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to your code at all, your code should do fine. The error message pertains to the chromedriver version and the current chrome browser you are using. Try to double check the chromedriver and chrome browser you are using for testing.

```
cannot determine loading status
```

Comment: Thank you - as mentioned in my original post, both the chromedriver and chrome version are the same. However, I know there have been issues with chromedriver103. Your response, confirms it is the chromedriver103 issue rather than my code specifically.